# How to pronounce word 'rather' in American English?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

When I'm checking the pronunciation of the word 'rather', it seems that the letter 'a' has two different pronunciations in American English. First one is same like letter 'a' in 'father', and the second one is like letter 'a' in word 'bat'. Which one is the most common one that people normally use?

Comment: They are both used. Amercan English has several dialects. You might hear the 'a' as in *father* in New England and other northern states, and the 'a' as in *rather* in a lot of other places. People normally use the one they are most comfortable with.

Comment: How did you find this out? Generally, you should provide your sources, if possible. I don't think I've ever heard the _father_ version (not saying it doesn't exist).

Comment: @Max The "broad a" pronunciation of _rather_ is a marker of what is sometimes called the "mid-Atlantic" accent. It is traditionally passed along to the studentry of Phillips Exeter, Choate, Andover, and other east coast preparatory schools in the U.S. It is also widely affected. See this [link](http://www.antimoon.com/forum/t8298.htm) for a discussion of the word.

Comment: @HenryWang You will always be correct if you pronounce _rather_ with a "flat a" as in _bat._

Comment: @P.E.Dant I have a feeling I'm not pronouncing "Phillips Exeter, Choate, Andover" right, haha.

Comment: @Max I found it on google translate

Comment: @HenryWang Google "translate" has questionable value for an English learner. If you speak Chinese, of what English phrase do you think the following is a "translation?" 他没有机会的幽灵。

Comment: Yes, could you please share the source you came across this information in?

Comment: @P.E. Dant: "He didn't have a snowball's chance in hell"?

Answer (score 2):

The most common way in American English is like the "a" in "bat".

Here's an [audible example.](https://youtu.be/TfANA35Sspk)